# How to make a html element load after another despite the order of the code?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am looking for a way how to make a html element load after another html element is loaded.

Is there any way?

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<php /* some php code */ ?>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to make table1 load after table2 with keeping the same code order as displayed above?

Comment: What __real__ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The php code calculates some values and the top table does not display the totals, as the bottom table does. I tried replacing the values in the top table from the bottom table using str_replace, but didnt work. So I am looking for some other way.

Comment: You could output them in reverse order, and then use flexbox’ `order` property to get them displayed in different order again … but that is probably not the best solution, if the data in both tables is related. _“I tried replacing the values in the top table from the bottom table using str_replace, but didnt work.”_ - can you show us what you tried, please? (Another little trick I sometimes use in a situation like this, is to use sprintf - the first table gets assembled as a string , %… placeholders put in the places where I want to insert additional values later …)

Comment: _“The php code calculates some values and the top table does not display the totals, as the bottom table does.”_ - why is that PHP code _between_ those two tables then, and not before both of them …?

Comment: The php code has to be in the middle.. The php code basically writes out products in another table in between in lines - product names, prices, costs etc.. and Table1 and Table2 are just summary tables at the top and bottom of the whole chunk. So the code order needs to remain the way it is :(.

Comment: just draw the tables also using `php` or any template engine like https://twig.symfony.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's just going to be like this instead:

```
<php /* some php code */ ?>

<table id="table1">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Do all the PHP processing necessary to create the data needed for *both tables* before you output anything. Then output the tables in order using the processed data. If you're outputting the first table as you fetch data from some source like a database, that means you'll need to fetch that data into an array temporarily until you've processed it rather than outputting it immediately.

if `<php /* some php code */ ?>` produces output that needs to go between table 1 and table 2, this can still work a few different ways, for example using output buffering.

```
<?php
ob_start();
 /* some php code */
$middle_content = ob_get_clean();
?>

<table id="table1">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php echo $middle_content ?>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think it should also be possible to calculate summary data on the data that goes in the middle chunk without outputting any of it, but it's hard to say exactly how that would work without seeing more of your code.

Comment: The problem is that the php code needs to be in the middle. Table1 and Table2 are only summary tables on the top nad bottom.

Comment: You can still do all of that processing before you send any output to the browser. There are multiple ways to do that. One way is to capture any of the output that goes between the two tables using output buffering.